# Getting "TypeError: $ is not a function" with (or without) jQuery Update installed

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm creating a custom theme and have run into a bit of a snag.  Drupal won't recognize jQuery even though I have jQuery Update module enabled.

The error in console:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$(document).read(function() { alert('hit'); });
```

My .info just to be thorough:

```
name = Theme
description = The Theme
core = 7.x

stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
scripts[] = js/scripts.js

regions[header]         = Header
regions[highlighted]    = Highlighted
regions[help]           = Help
regions[content]        = Content
regions[sidebar_first]  = First sidebar
regions[bottom]         = Page bottom

;Hidden Regions
regions[page_top] = Page Top;
regions[page_bottom] = Page Bottom

features[] = logo
features[] = node_user_picture
features[] = comment_user_picture
features[] = favicon
features[] = main_menu
features[] = secondary_menu
```

Head tag on view source with jQuery Update set to 1.10:

```
    <head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/TLSConnect/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<title>Welcome to TLSConnect | TLSConnect</title>
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/system/system.base.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/system/system.menus.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/system/system.messages.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/system/system.theme.css?mxpb1v");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/overlay/overlay-parent.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/contextual/contextual.css?mxpb1v");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/comment/comment.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/field/theme/field.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/node/node.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/search/search.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/user/user.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.uid1.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu_toolbar/admin_menu_toolbar.css?mxpb1v");
@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?mxpb1v");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/themes/ukvi/css/style.css?mxpb1v");</style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/misc/drupal.js?mxpb1v"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js?v=1.10.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/misc/1.9/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js?v=1.2.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/misc/1.9/overlay-parent.js?v=1.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/modules/contextual/contextual.js?v=1.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.js?mxpb1v"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu_toolbar/admin_menu_toolbar.js?mxpb1v"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/TLSConnect/sites/all/themes/ukvi/js/scripts.js?mxpb1v"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/TLSConnect\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"ukvi","theme_token":"YdYlp6PGGL8uOVLaL_gtRv-n5Z8pyvsoVoSd7spnI0E","js":{"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/jquery\/1.10\/jquery.min.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/ui\/ui\/minified\/jquery.ui.core.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/misc\/1.9\/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/jquery_update\/replace\/misc\/1.9\/overlay-parent.js":1,"modules\/contextual\/contextual.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/admin_menu\/admin_menu.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/admin_menu\/admin_menu_toolbar\/admin_menu_toolbar.js":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/ukvi\/js\/scripts.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,"misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,"modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.css":1,"modules\/contextual\/contextual.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"modules\/search\/search.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/admin_menu\/admin_menu.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/admin_menu\/admin_menu.uid1.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/admin_menu\/admin_menu_toolbar\/admin_menu_toolbar.css":1,"modules\/shortcut\/shortcut.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/ukvi\/css\/style.css":1}},"overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*","non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"},"pathPrefixes":[],"ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"},"tableHeaderOffset":"Drupal.admin.height","admin_menu":{"destination":"destination=node","hash":"0272a75636951355671f0daca74a5137","basePath":"\/TLSConnect\/?q=admin_menu","replacements":{".admin-menu-users a":"0 \/ 1"},"margin_top":1,"position_fixed":1,"toolbar":{"activeTrail":"\/TLSConnect\/"}}});
//--><!]]>
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery is namespaced in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility). You need a closure:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).read(function() { alert('hit'); });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That resulted in a new error (using firefox btw). 
    TypeError: $.browser is undefined
    if ($.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version) == 6) {

Comment: Which version of jQuery have you switched to? I know `$.browser` has been deprecated

Comment: In the jquery update module configuration I have it set to 1.10.1

Comment: That'll be it then - [jQuery.browser was removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: That was the ticket.  Set to 1.8 and works like a charm.  Thanks!